# How do I show data from .json file in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, json.net

Hello I am working on a project where I have to display data that I saved in .json file in DataGridView. Any help or answer will mean to me a lot. Thanks!!

Here is the code I made:

```
    private void showData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Aljaz\Documents\json1.json");
        var dateTimeFormat = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" };

        Employee employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json, dateTimeFormat);
        myDGView.DataSource = employee;
```

Comment: change `myDGView.DataSource = employee;` to `myDGView.DataSource = new List<Employee>(){employee};`

Comment: It worked, thank you very much :)